# Book Request: Windows Apps from Scratch

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am completely new to creating Windows applications so I bought [Professional Visual Studio 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470548657) to get started, but it's basically an overview of working with Visual Studio 2010 and not the "*build an app from scratch for dummies*" book I thought it was going to be.

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone could recommend a good book that offers a beginner level walk-through of creating a Windows application in `C#` from scratch so I can see the whole process from start to finish. Doing this by myself, it's much easier for me to learn by doing than to learn by theory.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of application are you hoping to develop? Let us know what your ideal first project is; web app? windows app? video game, console app etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Sams Teach Yourself Visual C# 2010 in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331012).

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of the referenced book, so this is obviously a slightly biased answer.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That was as close to what I had in mind as I could have found. Really good book for a Windows programming beginner.